# jqGrid virtual scrolling, drag scrollbar, requests all pages

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using a jqGrid as a frontend to a large mongo database.  The user wants to use the jqGrid filters to view the data in the database.  I'm sure this was performing well when we implemented it.  The filters have been getting passed along and applied to the mongo dataset and everything has been working fine.

But now if they drag the scrollbar down to mid point in the grid it takes a very long to to fetch the records to fill that view.  I turned on logging for the ajax interfaced to our mongo database to log the requests for pages coming from the jqGrid.  This dataset in mongo contains about 54,000 rows.

When the grid first loads it correctly asks for page 1 from the database.  If I page down slowly it asks for each page it needs to fill my viewport.  If I quickly drag the scrollbar to mid point and release it, the jqGrid requests every page in between the page I was on before dragging the scrollbar and the place I released it.  In this case I started on page 1 and it asked for page, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 460. That is about 460 individual page requests.

I thought we tested this initially and saw that it was skipping over pages it did not need and was going straight to the page(s) needed for where we released the scrollbar.

Am I mistaken about how virtual scrolling works? Does it request every page from the start of the file to the page I want to see?  I can't seem to find that level of detail in the documentation or via google searches to see how it should be acting.

Comment: It is a good idea to tell which version of jqGrid is used. This will help a lot. [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) example which does not go through every page can be found [here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/demos/jqgrid/paging/scrollbar/default.php)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tony.  The trick is what you set the scroll option to.  True or 1 (one) have very different behaviors.  From the docs for the scroll option "Creates dynamic scrolling grids. When enabled, the pager elements are disabled and we can use the vertical scrollbar to load data. When set to true the grid will always hold all the items from the start through to the latest point ever visited.   When scroll is set to an integer value (example 1), the grid will just hold the visible lines."

Comment: That is the reason that we  ask for example, since it is very difficult to reproduce every problematic situation.